# How to get source files from web.config into gulp for custom build

Tags: asp.net, gulp, web-config

Say, there is a specific css style defined in the `web.config` under `key` property like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="custom_theme" value="own-theme" />
</appSettings>
```

We use `gulp` to minify and bundle js and css in the project. 
Would it be possible to add the specific css, defined in `web.config`, into the list of sources in the `gulpfile.js`?

Comment: look into this https://www.npmjs.com/package/webconfig-parser

Comment: I'll check this out, thanks!